# Creating a line chart with a factor variable and a continuous variable in ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have the following data:

```
cefr_hours <- data.frame(cefr = as.factor(c("A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")),
                         hours = c(200, 400, 600, 800, 1200))
```

And I have created the following plot:

```
  ggplot(cefr_hours, aes(x = cefr, y = hours)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line() +
      theme_minimal() +
      labs(title = "Hours of Guided Learning Per Level", subtitle = "Source: Cambridge English Assessment") +
      xlab("CEFR Level") +
      ylab("Number of Hours")
```

[image]

What I want to do is draw an arrow through each of the points and then shade the area under the line and between the points similar to [this](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/162-add-a-shaded-area-under-a-curve/) meaning the colors between each of the levels would be different.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Do you want the arrow to link points ?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my points to make this idea clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty hacky, but it works.  I had to play with the data a bit to create "groups" of the data from A2 to B1, then B1 to B2 and so on.  I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

```
library(tidyverse)

cefr_hours <- data_frame(cefr = as.factor(c("A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")),
                         hours = c(200, 400, 600, 800, 1200))

#duplicate the data and create an indicator for group
cefr_hours <- cefr_hours %>% 
  bind_rows(cefr_hours) %>% 
  arrange(cefr) %>% 
  #create a group for A2 to B1, then B1 to B2, etc.
  mutate(group = ceiling((row_number() - 1) / 2)) %>% 
  #exclude the first and last points
  filter(group != min(group), group != max(group)) %>% 
  #convert from numeric to character
  mutate(group = letters[group])

ggplot(cefr_hours, aes(x= cefr, y=hours, group = group, fill = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = hours))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(arrow = arrow(angle = 15, ends = "last", type = "closed")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Hours of Guided Learning Per Level", 
       subtitle = "Source: Cambridge English Assessment",
       x = "CEFR Level",
       y = "Number of Hours") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Multi-colored area]

Comment: Edited to have multiple colors